# Vue Component - Rendering in wrong location

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am seeing strange behavior between a vue component and inline template.

**Example #1:** Inline Template

This is working as expected.  The vue component is unchanged as per example #2 below, the only difference is i've copied the template content into the tag as an inline template.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/pobffmnv/

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Current Clients</div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Client Name</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">No. Projects</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Time (7 days)</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <clientlistitem inline-template>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn small btn-primary">Edit</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </clientlistitem>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This correctly shows the following:
[image: Correct]

**Example #2:** Not inline

The following is my Vue template.  Below is the change to the code to remove the inline template.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld47hoy2/

```
<template>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn small btn-primary">
                    Edit
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>
```

Updated page code:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Current Clients</div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Client Name</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">No. Projects</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Time (7 days)</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <clientlistitem></clientlistitem>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

However, with the above, the following is displayed:
[image: Incorrect]

Looking at the source code of the output of the page, it appears to have put the rendered code BEFORE my table...?  I am expecting this to be between the `<tbody></tbody>` tags..

[image: Strange output]

Any reason why Vue would output the code to that location instead of the one expected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue here is that with [in DOM templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats) the templates are first rendered by the browser and HTML tables only allow certain kinds of elements inside. That being the case, the component `clientlistitem` is first rendered *outside* the table, then Vue compiles the template which results in the component in the wrong place.

To fix that, use the [`is` special attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is).

```
<tbody>
  <tr is="clientlistitem"></tr>
</tbody>
```

The browser will accept this and render the `tr` in the correct place, but Vue will interpret it as your component.

Here is your fiddle [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld47hoy2/3/).

Comment: Awesome. So do you say, using "is" is always safer, irrespective of any location in DOM?

Comment: @Kannaiyan No, using `is` is *only* required in very specific instances like tables. The safest would be to use a string template or a single file component. Take a look at the first link in the answer.